# How to modify a Word table in a document embedded in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I have so far been able to activate a Word document embedded in Excel, but I'm not able to modify the table's preferredwidth. How can I access this property through Excel VBA?

Here's what i have so far

```
Sub ok()

Set WDObj = Sheets("Sheet1").OLEObjects("Object 4")

WDObj.Activate
WDObj.ActiveDocument.Tables(1).PreferredWidthType = wdPreferredWidthPercent
WDObj.ActiveDocument.Tables(1).PreferredWidth = 95

End Sub
```

Comment: Do you get an error with this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to modify the content of an embedded Word document it's first necessary to access the embedded application, then the document itself. Once the code has accessed the `OLEObject` it then needs the actual `Object`, through which the application and the document can be addressed.

Note that it might be expedient to assign the OLE object a name, rather than relying on the one generated by Excel. Such names have a nasty tendency to change if additional objects are added or others deleted. Any name assigned explicitly will remain untouched. This needs to be run only one time on the worksheet (bases on the full sample code):

```
ws.OLEObjects("Object 4").Name = "WordDoc" 'for example, can be any string you prefer
```

Then, if you decide to do this, in the full code, it would be `ws.OLEObjects("WordDoc")`

At the end of the procedure the line `ws.Cells(1, 1).Select` deactivates the embedded object by selecting a cell on the sheet. If you want to leave the Word document active for the user to work with, simply remove that line.

```
Sub ok()
    Dim wb As Excel.Workbook
    Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim doc As Object 'Word.Document
    Dim wdObj As Object, wdTable As Object 'Word.Table

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set wdObj = ws.OLEObjects("Object 4")
    wdObj.Activate
    Set doc = wdObj.Object.Application.ActiveDocument
    Set wdTable = doc.Tables(1)
    wdTable.PreferredWidthType = 2 ' Word.WdPreferredWidthType.wdPreferredWidthPercent
    wdTable.PreferredWidth = 95
    ws.Cells(1, 1).Select
End Sub
```