# How to recognize an embedded Word document as "open"?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I need to export the contents of Excel cells to specific bookmarks in a Word document embedded in the same Excel file.

```vb
Sub Provareport()   
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim wd As Object
    Dim oEmbFile As Object
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Modello")
    Set wd = CreateObject("Word.application")

    'opening the embedded document    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Set oEmbFile = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("BANCHE").OLEObjects("Reword")
    oEmbFile.Verb Verb:=xlPrimary
    Set oEmbFile = Nothing
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    With wd.ActiveDocument
        .Bookmarks("Denominazione").Range.Text = ws.Range("G13").Value
        .Bookmarks("SNDG").Range.Text = ws.Range("F13").Value
        .Bookmarks("Organo_deliberante").Range.Text = ws.Range("I13").Value
        .Bookmarks("Headline").Range.Text = ws.Range("B80").Value
        .Bookmarks("Attivo").Range.Text = ws.Range("B81").Value
        .Bookmarks("Passivo").Range.Text = ws.Range("B90").Value
        .Bookmarks("LCRNSFR").Range.Text = ws.Range("B93").Value
        .Bookmarks("Patrimonializzazione").Range.Text = ws.Range("B94").Value
        .Bookmarks("Patrimonio2").Range.Text = ws.Range("B95").Value
        .Bookmarks("Conto_economico").Range.Text = ws.Range("B98").Value
        .Bookmarks("Conto_economico2").Range.Text = ws.Range("B100").Value
        .Bookmarks("Conto_economico3").Range.Text = ws.Range("B105").Value
        .Bookmarks("Conto_economico4").Range.Text = ws.Range("B108").Value
    End With

    Set doc = Nothing
    Set wd = Nothing

End Sub
```

The code stops at the line:

```
With wd.ActiveDocument
```

The following error appears:

> "run time error '4248'
>   This command is not available because no document is open"

However, the Word document is open.

Comment: You create a Word Application and open a document independently so you have no idea whether they are in the same Application or if you have two Applications, one of which will be hidden.  Rather than `Set wd = CreateObject("Word.application")` try something like `Set wd = oEmbFile.Application` after you have opened the embedded file.

Comment: Your wd object is pointing to a different instance of Word from the one you've opened the document in. You need to set wd after you've opened the document and use GetObject not createobject

Comment: Thanks to everybody. In the end I adopted the solution provided by Harassed Dad.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to modify a Word table in a document embedded in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54202284/how-to-modify-a-word-table-in-a-document-embedded-in-excel)

Answer (score 0):

as correctly pointed out by Gareth you are working with different instances of word. It is assumed reference to Microsoft Word Object library has been already added.

Then try in declare section

```
Dim wd As Word.Document
```

and finally

```
    Set oEmbFile = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("BANCHE").OLEObjects("Reword")
    oEmbFile.Verb Verb:=xlPrimary
    Set wd = oEmbFile.Object

    With wd
    '
    '
    '
    '

    End With
```

above code work for editing in the location and seems sufficient for present objective. However for opening with full word window and ribbon etc may try

```
oEmbFile.Verb Verb:=xlVerbOpen
```